# Package inputenc error unicode character − (u+200E)

Tags: tables, unicode, input-encodings, newunicodechar

Two of my tables in TexStudio are having the error: package inputenc error unicode character − (U+200E)not set up for use in LaTeX. Anybody knows what the exact problem is?

SOLVED: invisible character before Lauraceae

My first table is and the error appears for `\end{tabular}`:

```latex
\begin{table}[ht]
    \scriptsize
    \centering
    \captionsetup{type=table}
    \caption[The amount of ecological relevant \texorpdfstring{g\textsubscript{s}}{gs}-VPD curves for the different genera. ]{The total number of ecological relevant \texorpdfstring{g\textsubscript{s}}{gs}-VPD curves for the different genera. The associated altitude and growth form are displayed as well.}
    \label{tab:inventory}
    \scalebox{1.5}{
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
        \hline
        Genus                          & Growth form & Altitude (m) & \#gs-VPD curves \\ \hline
        Asteraceae Mikania             & Liana       & 400          & 2               \\
        Cucurbitaceae Cayaponia        & Liana       & 400          & 2               \\
        Clusiaceae Clusia              & Liana       & 1100         & 3               \\
        Ericaceae Psammisia            & Liana       & 1100         & 1               \\
        Sapindaceae Serjania           & Liana       & 1100         & 1               \\
        Asteraceae Mikania             & Liana       & 2200         & 5               \\
        Cucurbitaceae Gurania          & Liana       & 2200         & 1               \\
        Gobiesocidae Gouania           & Liana       & 2200         & 2               \\
        Vitaceae Cissus                & Liana       & 2200         & 1               \\
        Burseraceae Protium            & Tree        & 400          & 1               \\
        Urticaceae Cecropia            & Tree        & 400          & 3               \\
        Urticaceae Pourouma            & Tree        & 400          & 2               \\
        Clusiaceae Tovomita            & Tree        & 1100         & 5               \\
        Dichapetalaceae Stephanopodium & Tree        & 1100         & 1               \\
        ‎Lauraceae Ocotea               & Tree        & 1100         & 2               \\
        Leguminosae Dussia             & Tree        & 1100         & 1               \\
        Myristicaceae Otoba            & Tree        & 1100         & 1               \\
        Actinidiaceae Saurauia         & Tree        & 2200         & 1               \\
        Sapindaceae Billia             & Tree        & 2200         & 3               \\
        Araliaceae Oreopanax           & Tree        & 3000         & 2               \\
        Ericaceae Cavendishia          & Tree        & 3000         & 1               \\
        Rosaceae Rubus                 & Tree        & 3000         & 2               \\
        Rubiaceae Palicourea           & Tree        & 3000         & 2               \\
        Siparunaceae Siparuna          & Tree        & 3000         & 1               \\ \hline
        \textbf{Total}                 &             &              & \textbf{46}     \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

My second table is and the error appears at Lauraceae Ocotea floribunda

```latex
& Tree        & 1100     & 3            & 0           & 3            \\
```

```latex
\begin{longtable}{llllll}
    \caption[The amount of \texorpdfstring{g\textsubscript{s}}{gs}-VPD curves, light response curves and SLA for the different genera. ]{The amount of measured \texorpdfstring{g\textsubscript{s}}{gs}-VPD curves, light response curves and SLA for the different genera (or species if the plant was determined on species level). The associated altitude and growth form are displayed as well.}
    \label{tab:inventoryalles}  \\
    \hline
    Genus or species if known                & Growth form & Altitude & \#gs-VPD     & \#A-PAR     & \#SLA        \\ \hline
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \endhead
    %
    \hline
    \endfoot
    %
    \endlastfoot
    %
    Asteraceae Mikania                       & Liana       & 400      & 14           & 1           & 13           \\
    Cucurbitaceae Cayaponia                  & Liana       & 400      & 2            & 0           & 2            \\
    Hydrangeaceae Hydrangea                  & Liana       & 400      & 3            & 1           & 5            \\
    Clusiaceae Clusia                        & Liana       & 1100     & 9            & 0           & 9            \\
    Ericaceae Psammisia                      & Liana       & 1100     & 3            & 2           & 5            \\
    Melastomataceae Blakea                   & Liana       & 1100     & 2            & 0           & 2            \\
    Sapindaceae Serjania                     & Liana       & 1100     & 5            & 0           & 5            \\
    Aristolochiaceae Aristolochia            & Liana       & 2200     & 3            & 0           & 3            \\
    Asteraceae Mikania                       & Liana       & 2200     & 8            & 0           & 8            \\
    Cucurbitaceae Gurania                    & Liana       & 2200     & 3            & 0           & 3            \\
    Gobiesocidae Gouania                     & Liana       & 2200     & 2            & 0           & 2            \\
    Vitaceae Cissu                           & Liana       & 2200     & 3            & 1           & 4            \\
    Asteraceae Mikania                       & Liana       & 3000     & 2            & 0           & 2            \\
    Smilacaceae Smilax                       & Liana       & 3000     & 3            & 0           & 3            \\
    Annonaceae Rollinia mucosa               & Tree        & 400      & 0            & 1           & 2            \\
    Burseraceae Protium                      & Tree        & 400      & 2            & 0           & 2            \\
    Lecythidaceae Grias neuberthii           & Tree        & 400      & 2            & 0           & 2            \\
    Malvaceae Theobroma gileri               & Tree        & 400      & 2            & 0           & 2            \\
    Meliaceae Guarea                         & Tree        & 400      & 5            & 0           & 5            \\
    Phyllanthaceae Hieronyma alchorneoides   & Tree        & 400      & 0            & 1           & 2            \\
    Urticaceae Cecropia hastae               & Tree        & 400      & 6            & 0           & 6            \\
    Urticaceae Pourouma                      & Tree        & 400      & 5            & 1           & 0            \\
    Clusiaceae Tovomita weddelliana          & Tree        & 1100     & 6            & 1           & 6            \\
    Dichapetalaceae Dichapetalum             & Tree        & 1100     & 3            & 1           & 4            \\
    Dichapetalaceae Stephanopodium angulatum & Tree        & 1100     & 3            & 0           & 3            \\
    Lauraceae Caryodaphnopsis theobromifolia & Tree        & 1100     & 0            & 1           & 1            \\
    ‎Lauraceae Ocotea floribunda              & Tree        & 1100     & 3            & 0           & 3            \\
    Lauraceae Ocotea fraxifera               & Tree        & 1100     & 2            & 0           & 2            \\
    Leguminosae Dussia                       & Tree        & 1100     & 3            & 0           & 3            \\
    Myristicaceae Otoba gordonifolia         & Tree        & 1100     & 3            & 2           & 5            \\
    Actinidiaceae Saurauia                   & Tree        & 2200     & 3            & 0           & 3            \\
    Lauraceae Nectandra subbullata           & Tree        & 2200     & 2            & 0           & 2            \\
    Moraceae Morus insignis                  & Tree        & 2200     & 3            & 0           & 3            \\
    Phyllanthaceae Hieronyma asperifolia     & Tree        & 2200     & 3            & 1           & 4            \\
    Sapindaceae Billia rosea                 & Tree        & 2200     & 5            & 1           & 5            \\
    Theaceae Gordonia fruticos               & Tree        & 2200     & 1            & 0           & 0            \\
    Adoxaceae Viburnum hallii                & Tree        & 3000     & 2            & 0           & 2            \\
    Araliaceae Oreopanax                     & Tree        & 3000     & 2            & 0           & 2            \\
    Betulaceae Alnus acuminata               & Tree        & 3000     & 4            & 0           & 4            \\
    Ericaceae Cavendishia bracteata          & Tree        & 3000     & 3            & 0           & 3            \\
    Rosaceae Rubus                           & Tree        & 3000     & 3            & 0           & 3            \\
    Rubiaceae Palicourea                     & Tree        & 3000     & 2            & 0           & 2            \\
    Siparunaceae Siparuna                    & Tree        & 3000     & 3            & 0           & 3            \\
    Unknown 1                                & Unknown     & 3000     & 0            & 1           & 0            \\
    Unknown 2                                & Unknown     & 3000     & 0            & 1           & 0            \\
    Unknown 3                                & Unknown     & 3000     & 0            & 1           & 0            \\ \hline
    \textbf{Total}                           &             &          & \textbf{143} & \textbf{18} & \textbf{150} \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

The settings are:

```
%% PACKAGES FOR LANGUAGE STUFF %%
\usepackage[latin1,utf8]{inputenc}                      %
\usepackage[english]{babel}                     
\input{hyphenation.tex}                                 

%% PACKAGES FOR LAYOUT AND WRITING%%
\usepackage{hyperref}                                   %
\usepackage[times]{quotchap}                            
\usepackage[sumlimits]{amsmath}                         
\usepackage{amsthm}                                     
\usepackage[vlined,ruled]{algorithm2e}                  
\usepackage{verbatim}                                   
\usepackage{float}                                      
\usepackage[a4paper,verbose, centering,reversemp]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                                   
\usepackage{times}                                      
\usepackage{wrapfig}                                    
\usepackage{floatflt}                                   
\usepackage[round]{natbib}                              
\usepackage{xcolor}                                     
\usepackage{multicol}                                   
\usepackage{graphicx}                                   
%\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}                         
\usepackage{enumitem}                                   
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}                   
\usepackage[calcwidth,newparttoc]{titlesec}             
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{isotope} 
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{nomencl} 
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

%refer to multiple figures:
%\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.}
\newcommand\crefrangeconjunction{--}


%% PACKAGES FOR TABLES %%
    \usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}                          
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}        
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}   
    \usepackage{multirow}                                   
    \usepackage{hhline}                                     
    \usepackage[font={small},labelfont={bf},center]{caption} 
    \usepackage{lscape}                                     
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{graphicx}


%% OTHER PACKAGES
\usepackage{datetime}                                   
\usepackage{pdfpages}                                   

\usepackage{amssymb,listings,color,textcomp,marvosym,flafter,longtable,subcaption,amsfonts,rotating}
\usepackage{array,pstricks,listings}

\definecolor{chaptergray}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}
\parskip=\medskipamount

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{jpg,png}

\input{page_layout_definition}                          
{label}
\newcommand{\mijnfiguur}[5][ht]{            
    \begin{figure}[#1]                      
        \begin{center}                     
            \includegraphics[#2]{#3}        
        \end{center}
        \caption{#4}          
        \label{#5}
    \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}                
\lstset{language=Matlab,commentstyle=, framexleftmargin=5mm,belowcaptionskip=5mm,
frame=single,basicstyle={\ttfamily\small},
stringstyle=\small,commentstyle=\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.53,0.53},
backgroundcolor=\color[rgb]{0.93,0.93,0.93},showspaces=false,framexleftmargin=-2pt,showstringspaces=false,upquote=true}

\frontmatter
    \include{Titelpagina}                
    \newpage\mbox{}\newpage
    \inputencoding{latin1}
    \include{Copyright}                 
    \newpage\mbox{}\newpage
    \inputencoding{utf8}
    \include{Abstract}
    \include{Samenvatting}
    \include{Resumen}
    \include{Voorwoord}
    \newpage\mbox{}\newpage

    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \include{Abbreviations}


\mainmatter                             
    \include{chapter2}
    \include{chapter1}
    \include{chapter3}
    \include{chapter4}
    \include{chapter5}
    \include{chapter6}

\let\secfnt\undefined
\newfont{\secfnt}{ptmb8t at 9pt}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \small
    %\bibliographystyle{amsplain}       
    \bibliographystyle{myplainnat}      
    \bibliography{library}              
\end{multicols}

\include{Bijlagen}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Neither of your tables has the − characters. Please post a full example code i.e. a code starting with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` which reproduces the problem so that we can have a look. If you can find out the − character, just substitute it with `--`, because LaTeX doesn't accept − but allows you to use `--` for en-dashes.

Comment: Maybe the \#gs-VPD curves?

Comment: No. Your error character is the en-dash. I don't see it here

Comment: My other tables all work in the same document. I searched (control F) for '–' and I found nothing.

Comment: That is unusual. Can you reproduce the problem with an example code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: The question is edited!

Comment: Please try making your code a minimal (meaning without any packages or commands you don't need to illustrate the problem) working (meaning we can compile it as is; if you need to load external files (like `hyphenation.tex`) you need to provide those, too) example.

Comment: the first error is the invisible character just prior to `Lauraceae Ocotea`

Answer (score 2):

The two rogue characters are a [Left-to-right mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) and are invisible, possibly caught up in a copy and paste action (Possibly from a word generated PDF)

I have gone back over the many edits to try and track down the second `‎` but no joy (either it was not pasted correctly, or it was edited out early OR it is an echo in the compilation of the first one) once you remove the rogue character found just before Lauraceae

```
           Dichapetalaceae Stephanopodium & Tree        & 1100         & 1               \\  
[HERE I AM]Lauraceae Ocotea               & Tree        & 1100         & 2               \\  
           Leguminosae Dussia             & Tree        & 1100         & 1               \\
```

Then compile again to see if both have gone

Comment: Thank you so much! It finally worked. Only the end{tabular}} is still not working.

Comment: That one is also working now, it was again the invisible character for Lauraceae. Thank you all!